# working with objects in an array in javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have chosen some of div elements in HTML and save them in an array

```
var Div = $(".etc") ;
```

i want to use this notation to slide-toggle Div elements with this code ;

```
Div[0].slideToggle(...) ;
```

but it doesn't work and doesn't toggle the element .
although i try to alert element's value or name and other attributes but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

The bracket notation returns DOM elements, which do not have a `slideToggle` method. What you want is [`.eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/), which filters in the same manner but returns jQuery objects instead:

```
Div.eq(0).slideToggle(...) ;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `eq()`:

```
Div.eq(0).slideToggle(...);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$(Div[0]).slideToggle(...) ;
```

Or:

```
Div.eq(0).slideToggle(...) ;
```

**[.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)**

Comment: it is better to use .eq() as you already have a jquery object